# TableView assigning image to cell in TVC

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, tableview

Having a problem with this code. Basically i'm trying to populate a table cell using an image im pulling from twitter. The url field here has the value http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/796924570150301696/35nSG5nN_normal.jpg but for some reason the print("REACHED") is never printed. Any help/suggestions appreciated!

code snippet:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
    let tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let url = tweet.user.profileImageURL!
    print(url.absoluteString)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    if (data == nil){
    } else {
        print("REACHED")
        cell.avatarImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
    cell.tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)` Avoid that! It's synchrone and blocking the UI.

Comment: @Larme any suggestions on an alternative approach?

Comment: This library might be useful:         https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
func example() {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let url = URL(string: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/796924570150301696/35nSG5nN_normal.jpg")

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        print("REACHED")
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } catch {
        print("received this error:\n\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work right away, at least you'll have an error message to help you figure it out. Good luck!

Edit:
You should make sure you have updated your Info.plist to include an entry for:

> App Transport Security Settings

Without this you will not have access to other sites.
[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: I don't see a path to the file. Add a breakpoint in the method above where you load the file. Step through and verify as you go.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: This originally gave me a "cannot open file error" which lead me to re-examine my plist source code and by adding `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>` I was able to get it running. Thanks @Mozahler

Comment: Funny, that was going to be my next suggestion. I was about to copy and paste from my Info.plist. I quickly tested the code in an app that had  NSAPPTransportSecurity set.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips for an easy life…

- Don't force unwrap
- Don't download on the main queue
- Don't expose your cell's `IBOutlet`s

---

```
let imageQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imageQueue", qos: DispatchQoS.background)

class TweetCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet fileprivate var avatarImage: UIImageView!

    var tweet: Tweet {        
        didSet {
            guard let url = tweet.user.profileImageURL else { return }

            loadImage(url: url)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func loadImage(url: URL) {
        imageQueue.async {

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url) 

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.avatarImage.image = UIImage(data: data)        
                }

            } catch {
                // Handle error
            }    
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
    cell.tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```